# storing multiple values in c language without using arrays

Tags: c

have to reverse number and get difference between normal and reverse number.
 The input consists of N numbers, where N is an arbitrary positive integer. The first line of the input
   contains only a positive integer N. Then follows one or more lines with the N numbers; these numbers
    should all be non-negative and may be single or multiple digits. These are the original numbers you need
   to generate their N corresponding magic numbers.

i was thinking maybe using a while loop and just doing one input at a time, anyone have any thoughts?

what i have so far

```
#include <stdio.h>

int reverseInteger();
int generateMagicNumber();

int main()
{
    int n,i;
    char all;
    printf("How many magic numbers do you want");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    while (i<n){        //
        while (n != 0) //reversing number
            {
                rev = rev * 10;
                rev = rev + n%10;
                n = n/10;
                i++;
                all =  n;
            }
    }
}
```

Assignment 1:

> Reverse Number Magic Sequence
>
> Due: Wednesday January 27, 2016 11:59pm EST
>
> A reverse number is a number written in arabic numerals, but where the
>   order of digits is reversed. The first digit becomes the last and vice
>   versa. For example, the number 1245 when its digits are reversed it
>   would become 5421. Note that all the leading zeros are omitted. That
>   means if the number ends with a zero, the zero is lost by reversing
>   (e.g. 1200 gives 21). Also note that the reversed number never has any
>   trailing zeros. Finally, every single digit number (i.e. 0-9) is its
>   own reverse number. In order to generate a magic number, we reverse a
>   given original number and store the absolute value of the difference
>   between the original number and its reversed version. For example,
>   given the number 476, we will generate the reverse number 674 and then
>   compute the absolute value of the difference between 476 and 674 to be
>   198. We then reverse 198 to display the number 891; we call that the magic number!
>
> We need your help to compute the magic numbers of a given sequence.
>   Your task is to calculate the difference between a given number and
>   its reverse version, and output the reverse of the difference. Of
>   course, the result is not unique because any particular number is a
>   reversed form of several numbers (e.g. 21 could be 12, 120 or 1200
>   before reversing). Thus we must assume that no zeros were lost by
>   reversing (e.g. assume that the original number was 12).
>
> Input 
>   The
>   input consists of N numbers, where N is an arbitrary positive integer.
>   The first line of the input contains only a positive integer N. Then
>   follows one or more lines with the N numbers; these numbers should all
>   be non-negative and may be single or multiple digits. These are the
>   original numbers you need to generate their N corresponding magic
>   numbers.
>
> Output 
>   For each original number in the sequence, print
>   exactly one integer – its magic number. Omit any leading zeros in the
>   output. On a separate line, output the largest absolute difference
>   encountered in the sequence. Sample Input
>
> ```
> 6
> 24 1 4358 754 305 794
> Sample Output
> 81 0 6714 792 891 792
> 4176
> ```
>
> Specific Requirements: [15 pts]
>
> - [ 3 pts] Write a function called reverseInteger, that takes as input an unsigned integer and returns its reversed digits version as an
>     unsigned integer.
> - [ 3 pts] Write a function called generateMagicNumber, that takes as input an unsigned integer and return its magic number as described in
>     the problem.
> - [ 3 pts] Display the sequence of magic numbers correctly. (shown in the script file)
> - [ 2 pts] Display the largest absolute difference (shown in the script file)
> - [ 3 pts] Demonstrate the complete program using a main function capable of processing the input of any sequence and producing its
>     corresponding output.
> - [ 1 pt] Compilation on the CS server gcc compiler without errors and warnings.
>
> Failure to properly document your entire code will receive a mark of
>   zero.
>
> You are to submit the following:
>
> - Source code file: assign1.c
> - Script file demonstrating the compilation and execution : assign1.txt
>
> To generate the script file use the following command from the CS
>   server:
>
> ```
> cp assign1.c assign1.backup
> typescript assign1.txt
> cc assign1.c
> a.out
> [test your code here with at least 3 different input test cases in addition to the example given]
> exit
> [These steps will create a file called assign1.txt. Do not edit its contents - just submit it!]
> ```
>
> Hint: This table explains the work done in this example:
>
> ```
> Originalnumber
> Reverse Absolute difference
> Reverse (Magic number)
>
> X Xr |X-Xr| |X-Xr|r
> 24 42 18 81
> 1 1 0 0
> 4358 8534 4176 6714
> 754 457 297 792
> 305 503 198 891
> 794 497 297 792
> ```
>
> Note that your program should not use arrays and should be able to
>   read a sequence of N size, for any value of N (a 32 bit integer). Of
>   course, memory space optimization should be considered since there is
>   no need to store all the N numbers in memory all at once at any given
>   time.

Comment: Your approach seems correct, go ahead, write some code!

Comment: If you only need to deal with one of them at a time, that should work fine. You only need an array if you need to process the entire collection at the same time.

Comment: @Barmar Alright, im not sure how to print them all out at the end

Comment: Do you have to wait until the end to print them all out? Can't you print each one in the loop that generates it?

Comment: @Barmar have to wait till the end, i was thinking of adding the answers into a string and printing that string out at the end?

Comment: A C string is an array.

Comment: Why don't you want to use an array, anyway?

Comment: How about using linked list?

Comment: @Barmar its an assignment and my prof doesnt want us to use an array.

Comment: @MikeCAT Never heard of it but will look it up! Thank you

Comment: @MikeCAT If this is an assignment, and they haven't been taught about structures and pointers yet, I can't believe he's expected to use a linked list.

Comment: You should read a new number in each iteration of the `while` loop.

Comment: @Barmar we learnt how to use arrays, pointers and all, just for this assignment he doesn't want the use for arrays.

Comment: I think we need to see the full wording of the assignment, so we understand all the requirements and restrictions.

Comment: @Barmar https://blackboard.uwindsor.ca/bbcswebdav/pid-297744-dt-content-rid-818360_1/courses/599015/assign1_rev1.pdf not sure if u can see it from here

Comment: It requires a login, I can't see it. Cut and paste the description into the question.

Comment: @Barmar not as expected lol sorry

Comment: I don't see anything in the requirements that says that you can't print each magic number immediately after calculating it in the loop.

Comment: @Barmar look at the way he wants us to output the information

Comment: The only thing you have to do at the end is print the largest absolute difference. You can do that with one variable, containing the largest difference found so far. In each iteration, you check whether the current difference is larger than this, and replace the value if it is.

Comment: @Barmar sweet, Thank you, ill write the code and ill get back to you. I appreciate your help, also do you think chqrlie is on the right track?

Comment: It's the right general structure for the program.

Answer (score 1):

You should read a new number in each iteration of the `while` loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int reverseInteger();
int generateMagicNumber();

int main() {
    int n, i;
    char all;
    printf("How many magic numbers do you want");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1)
        return 1;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int num, temp, rev, magic;
        if (scanf("%d", &num) != 1)
            return 2;

        rev = 0;
        temp = num;
        while (temp != 0) { //reversing number
            rev = rev * 10;
            rev = rev + temp % 10;
            temp = temp / 10;
        }
        if (rev < num)
            magic = num - rev;
        else
            magic = rev - num;
        printf("%d ", magic);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

If you enter all the numbers on one line, the answers will appear on a single line below it.

Comment: How does this print all the results at the end?

Comment: How were you able to post this answer when the question was put on hold 13 minutes ago?

Comment: @Barmar: I updated my answer.  I suppose I was able to post an answer because I opened the question before it was put on hold.  Since the OP posted the code, I think we should reopen it anyway.

Comment: @chqrlie hmm, i posted the question, but im going to have to transfer the input to other functions,

Comment: @Hassan Rammal - try it yourself and see if it "prints all the results".  Q: Are they all printed?  Q: Are they printed "at the end"?  What's the difference?  A: Do you need "char all" anymore? Could "char all" have printed the results even if you wanted it to?

Comment: @HassanRammal: you are going to have to write some mode code... I hope you got a better idea on what to do now.

Comment: @chqrlie i do! Thank you!

Comment: this code doesnt give me the reverse.

Comment: Heres what i got              How many magic numbers do you want4
12 13 42 23
                9 18 18 9

Comment: @chqrlie can you help please